# my code fills inside the stroke of my svg image only when I'm using sprite

Tags: css, svg, css-sprites

I have an svg logo that has some text path and icon path in the middle of the text. When it's inline and I use "fill: #fff", it fills the text only which is good.
When I'm using sprite and I use "fill: #fff", it doesn't change anything and everything is being filled in black, even inside the stroke of the icon, which it's not supposed to do.

Please check the css comments in the codepen to see screenshot of both examples.

codepen: https://codepen.io/rawan-al-faraj/pen/VggeWj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 792 612" style="enable-background:new 0 0 792 612;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:2.0134;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M393.12,298.67L393.12,298.67c-8.73,8.73-22.89,8.73-31.63,0l0,0c-7.56-7.56-7.56-19.81,0-27.37l15.81-15.81
            l15.81,15.81C400.68,278.86,400.68,291.11,393.12,298.67z"/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="391.31,300.47 377.31,286.46 363.3,300.47      "/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="395.76,296.02 377.31,277.57 358.85,296.02         "/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="398.2,289.65 377.31,268.76 356.4,289.66       "/>
        <line class="st0" x1="377.31" y1="255.48" x2="377.31" y2="268.6"/>
        <line class="st0" x1="377.31" y1="286.46" x2="377.31" y2="304.65"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M361.49,312.34L361.49,312.34c8.73-8.73,22.89-8.73,31.63,0l0,0c7.56,7.56,7.56,19.81,0,27.37l-15.81,15.81
            l-15.81-15.81C353.93,332.15,353.93,319.9,361.49,312.34z"/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="363.3,310.54 377.31,324.55 391.31,310.54      "/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="358.85,314.98 377.31,333.44 395.76,314.98         "/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="356.41,321.36 377.31,342.25 398.21,321.35         "/>
        <line class="st0" x1="377.31" y1="355.52" x2="377.31" y2="342.41"/>
        <line class="st0" x1="377.31" y1="324.55" x2="377.31" y2="306.35"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M384.14,321.32L384.14,321.32c-8.73-8.73-8.73-22.89,0-31.63l0,0c7.56-7.56,19.81-7.56,27.37,0l15.81,15.81
            l-15.81,15.81C403.95,328.88,391.7,328.88,384.14,321.32z"/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="382.34,319.51 396.35,305.5 382.34,291.5       "/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="386.79,323.96 405.24,305.5 386.79,287.05      "/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="393.16,326.4 414.05,305.5 393.15,284.6        "/>
        <line class="st0" x1="427.33" y1="305.5" x2="414.21" y2="305.5"/>
        <line class="st0" x1="396.35" y1="305.5" x2="378.16" y2="305.5"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M370.47,289.69L370.47,289.69c8.73,8.73,8.73,22.89,0,31.63v0c-7.56,7.56-19.81,7.56-27.37,0l-15.81-15.81
            l15.81-15.81C350.66,282.13,362.91,282.13,370.47,289.69z"/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="372.27,291.5 358.26,305.5 372.27,319.51       "/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="367.83,287.05 349.37,305.5 367.83,323.96      "/>
        <polyline class="st0" points="361.46,284.61 340.56,305.5 361.47,326.41      "/>
        <line class="st0" x1="327.29" y1="305.5" x2="340.4" y2="305.5"/>
        <line class="st0" x1="358.26" y1="305.5" x2="376.46" y2="305.5"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
    <path d="M231.96,314.57h-2.16v-21.24h12.81v1.92h-10.65v7.35h9.9v1.92h-9.9V314.57z"/>
    <path d="M252.72,314.57h-2.16v-21.24h6.24c1.04,0,2,0.1,2.9,0.3c0.89,0.2,1.66,0.53,2.31,0.98c0.65,0.45,1.15,1.04,1.51,1.75
        c0.36,0.72,0.54,1.6,0.54,2.64c0,0.78-0.14,1.49-0.42,2.13c-0.28,0.64-0.66,1.2-1.14,1.67c-0.48,0.47-1.05,0.85-1.71,1.12
        c-0.66,0.28-1.38,0.46-2.16,0.54l6.21,10.11h-2.64l-5.88-9.93h-3.6V314.57z M252.72,302.78h3.75c1.74,0,3.08-0.32,4.02-0.95
        c0.94-0.63,1.41-1.57,1.41-2.83c0-0.7-0.13-1.29-0.39-1.77c-0.26-0.48-0.62-0.87-1.08-1.17c-0.46-0.3-1.02-0.52-1.68-0.66
        c-0.66-0.14-1.39-0.21-2.19-0.21h-3.84V302.78z"/>
    <path d="M274.59,312.65h11.37v1.92h-13.53v-21.24h13.17v1.92h-11.01v7.29h10.29v1.92h-10.29V312.65z"/>
    <path d="M296.25,312.65h11.37v1.92h-13.53v-21.24h13.17v1.92h-11.01v7.29h10.29v1.92h-10.29V312.65z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <path d="M456.13,296.75c-0.46-0.64-1.05-1.15-1.77-1.54c-0.72-0.39-1.59-0.58-2.61-0.58c-0.52,0-1.05,0.08-1.59,0.24
        s-1.03,0.41-1.47,0.74c-0.44,0.33-0.79,0.75-1.06,1.24c-0.27,0.5-0.41,1.09-0.41,1.77s0.13,1.24,0.39,1.68
        c0.26,0.44,0.6,0.82,1.03,1.12c0.43,0.31,0.92,0.57,1.47,0.77c0.55,0.2,1.12,0.4,1.72,0.6c0.74,0.24,1.48,0.5,2.23,0.78
        s1.42,0.64,2.02,1.09s1.09,1.02,1.47,1.71c0.38,0.69,0.57,1.57,0.57,2.62c0,1.06-0.2,1.98-0.61,2.75c-0.4,0.77-0.93,1.41-1.58,1.91
        s-1.38,0.87-2.21,1.11c-0.83,0.24-1.67,0.36-2.5,0.36c-0.64,0-1.28-0.07-1.92-0.2c-0.64-0.13-1.25-0.33-1.83-0.58
        s-1.12-0.59-1.62-0.99c-0.5-0.4-0.94-0.86-1.32-1.38l1.86-1.38c0.46,0.76,1.1,1.4,1.93,1.91s1.8,0.76,2.93,0.76
        c0.54,0,1.09-0.08,1.65-0.25s1.07-0.43,1.51-0.78c0.45-0.35,0.82-0.78,1.11-1.29c0.29-0.51,0.44-1.11,0.44-1.79
        c0-0.74-0.15-1.36-0.44-1.85c-0.29-0.49-0.67-0.9-1.16-1.23c-0.48-0.33-1.03-0.6-1.65-0.83c-0.62-0.22-1.27-0.44-1.95-0.66
        c-0.7-0.22-1.39-0.47-2.07-0.75c-0.68-0.28-1.29-0.64-1.83-1.09s-0.97-1-1.3-1.67s-0.5-1.47-0.5-2.43c0-1.02,0.21-1.9,0.62-2.64
        c0.41-0.74,0.95-1.35,1.6-1.83c0.66-0.48,1.39-0.83,2.19-1.05c0.8-0.22,1.59-0.33,2.37-0.33c1.44,0,2.67,0.25,3.69,0.77
        c1.02,0.51,1.79,1.12,2.31,1.81L456.13,296.75z"/>
    <path d="M466.66,293.33h6c1.08,0,2.06,0.12,2.94,0.35c0.88,0.23,1.63,0.58,2.26,1.05s1.12,1.06,1.46,1.77s0.51,1.54,0.51,2.5
        s-0.18,1.8-0.53,2.5c-0.35,0.71-0.84,1.3-1.47,1.77s-1.39,0.83-2.28,1.06c-0.89,0.24-1.88,0.36-2.96,0.36h-3.78v9.87h-2.16V293.33z
         M468.82,302.87h3.66c1.7,0,2.99-0.33,3.87-0.99c0.88-0.66,1.32-1.62,1.32-2.88c0-1.32-0.46-2.28-1.37-2.89s-2.19-0.92-3.83-0.92
        h-3.66V302.87z"/>
    <path d="M490.12,314.57h-2.16v-21.24h2.16V314.57z"/>
    <path d="M501.82,314.57h-2.16v-21.24h6.24c1.04,0,2,0.1,2.89,0.3c0.89,0.2,1.66,0.53,2.31,0.98c0.65,0.45,1.15,1.04,1.51,1.75
        s0.54,1.6,0.54,2.64c0,0.78-0.14,1.49-0.42,2.13c-0.28,0.64-0.66,1.2-1.14,1.67c-0.48,0.47-1.05,0.85-1.71,1.12
        c-0.66,0.28-1.38,0.46-2.16,0.54l6.21,10.11h-2.64l-5.88-9.93h-3.6V314.57z M501.82,302.78h3.75c1.74,0,3.08-0.32,4.02-0.95
        S511,300.26,511,299c0-0.7-0.13-1.29-0.39-1.77c-0.26-0.48-0.62-0.87-1.08-1.17c-0.46-0.3-1.02-0.52-1.68-0.66
        c-0.66-0.14-1.39-0.21-2.19-0.21h-3.84V302.78z"/>
    <path d="M523.69,314.57h-2.16v-21.24h2.16V314.57z"/>
    <path d="M540.04,314.57h-2.16v-19.32h-7.11v-1.92h16.38v1.92h-7.11V314.57z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <path d="M290.36,333.98v8.43h-2.56v-8.43h-3v-2.19h8.56v2.19H290.36z"/>
    <path d="M300.21,342.41l-2.31-4.21h-0.87v4.21h-2.5v-10.62h4.05c0.51,0,1.01,0.05,1.49,0.16c0.48,0.11,0.92,0.28,1.3,0.53
        s0.69,0.58,0.92,0.99c0.23,0.41,0.34,0.92,0.34,1.53c0,0.72-0.19,1.33-0.58,1.82s-0.93,0.84-1.62,1.05l2.77,4.54H300.21z
         M300.11,335.05c0-0.25-0.05-0.45-0.16-0.61c-0.11-0.15-0.24-0.27-0.41-0.36c-0.17-0.08-0.35-0.14-0.56-0.17s-0.4-0.04-0.6-0.04
        h-1.37v2.47h1.22c0.21,0,0.43-0.02,0.65-0.05c0.22-0.03,0.42-0.1,0.6-0.19c0.18-0.09,0.33-0.22,0.44-0.39
        C300.05,335.54,300.11,335.32,300.11,335.05z"/>
    <path d="M311.67,342.41l-0.82-2.08h-4.11l-0.78,2.08h-2.79l4.46-10.62h2.49l4.41,10.62H311.67z M308.82,334.63l-1.35,3.65h2.67
        L308.82,334.63z"/>
    <path d="M320.22,342.41h-2.56l-4.02-10.62h2.88l2.46,7.53h0.06l2.45-7.53h2.83L320.22,342.41z"/>
    <path d="M325.19,342.41v-10.62h7.14v2.16h-4.67v2.01h4.41v2.06h-4.41v2.2h4.94v2.19H325.19z"/>
    <path d="M334.29,342.41v-10.62h2.58v8.38h4.11v2.24H334.29z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <path d="M422.51,342.41l-0.83-2.08h-4.11l-0.78,2.08H414l4.46-10.62h2.49l4.41,10.62H422.51z M419.66,334.63l-1.35,3.65h2.67
        L419.66,334.63z"/>
    <path d="M433.59,342.43c-0.7,0.17-1.45,0.25-2.27,0.25c-0.85,0-1.63-0.13-2.35-0.4c-0.71-0.27-1.33-0.65-1.84-1.14
        c-0.51-0.49-0.92-1.08-1.21-1.76c-0.29-0.69-0.44-1.45-0.44-2.29c0-0.85,0.15-1.62,0.44-2.31c0.29-0.69,0.7-1.28,1.22-1.76
        s1.13-0.86,1.83-1.12c0.7-0.26,1.46-0.39,2.26-0.39c0.84,0,1.62,0.13,2.34,0.38c0.72,0.25,1.3,0.6,1.75,1.03l-1.62,1.84
        c-0.25-0.29-0.58-0.53-0.99-0.71c-0.41-0.19-0.88-0.28-1.39-0.28c-0.45,0-0.87,0.08-1.25,0.25c-0.38,0.17-0.71,0.4-0.99,0.69
        c-0.28,0.29-0.5,0.64-0.65,1.05c-0.16,0.41-0.23,0.85-0.23,1.33c0,0.49,0.07,0.94,0.21,1.35c0.14,0.41,0.35,0.76,0.62,1.06
        c0.28,0.3,0.62,0.53,1.02,0.69c0.4,0.17,0.87,0.25,1.39,0.25c0.3,0,0.58-0.02,0.86-0.07c0.27-0.04,0.52-0.12,0.75-0.22v-1.94h-2.03
        v-2.07h4.38v5.62C434.89,342.04,434.28,342.26,433.59,342.43z"/>
    <path d="M437.51,342.41v-10.62h7.14v2.16h-4.67v2.01h4.41v2.06h-4.41v2.2h4.93v2.19H437.51z"/>
    <path d="M453.36,342.41l-4.28-6.95h-0.04l0.06,6.95h-2.49v-10.62h2.92l4.26,6.93h0.05l-0.06-6.93h2.49v10.62H453.36z"/>
    <path d="M466.07,342.22c-0.69,0.32-1.49,0.47-2.38,0.47c-0.82,0-1.58-0.13-2.27-0.41c-0.7-0.27-1.3-0.65-1.81-1.15
        s-0.91-1.09-1.2-1.78c-0.29-0.69-0.43-1.45-0.43-2.28c0-0.85,0.15-1.62,0.44-2.31c0.29-0.69,0.7-1.28,1.22-1.76
        c0.52-0.49,1.13-0.86,1.83-1.12c0.7-0.26,1.45-0.39,2.26-0.39c0.75,0,1.49,0.13,2.21,0.4c0.73,0.27,1.31,0.65,1.76,1.16l-1.74,1.74
        c-0.24-0.33-0.56-0.57-0.95-0.73c-0.39-0.16-0.79-0.24-1.2-0.24c-0.45,0-0.86,0.08-1.24,0.25c-0.38,0.16-0.7,0.39-0.97,0.68
        c-0.27,0.29-0.48,0.63-0.63,1.03c-0.15,0.39-0.22,0.83-0.22,1.3c0,0.48,0.07,0.92,0.22,1.32s0.36,0.74,0.62,1.03
        c0.27,0.29,0.58,0.51,0.95,0.67c0.37,0.16,0.77,0.24,1.21,0.24c0.51,0,0.96-0.1,1.33-0.3s0.68-0.46,0.92-0.78l1.79,1.68
        C467.34,341.48,466.76,341.91,466.07,342.22z"/>
    <path d="M473.88,337.91v4.5h-2.57v-4.5l-3.99-6.12h3.1l2.26,3.93l2.27-3.93h3L473.88,337.91z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

The sprite:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <symbol version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 792 612" style="enable-background:new 0 0 792 612;" xml:space="preserve">
     <style type="text/css">
      .st0{fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:2.0134;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    </style>
    <g>
      <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M393.12,298.67L393.12,298.67c-8.73,8.73-22.89,8.73-31.63,0l0,0c-7.56-7.56-7.56-19.81,0-27.37l15.81-15.81
          l15.81,15.81C400.68,278.86,400.68,291.11,393.12,298.67z"/>
          <polyline class="st0" points="391.31,300.47 377.31,286.46 363.3,300.47    "/>
          <polyline class="st0" points="395.76,296.02 377.31,277.57 358.85,296.02     "/>
          <polyline class="st0" points="398.2,289.65 377.31,268.76 356.4,289.66     "/>
          <line class="st0" x1="377.31" y1="255.48" x2="377.31" y2="268.6"/>
          <line class="st0" x1="377.31" y1="286.46" x2="377.31" y2="304.65"/>
        </g>
        <g>
          <path class="st0" d="M361.49,312.34L361.49,312.34c8.73-8.73,22.89-8.73,31.63,0l0,0c7.56,7.56,7.56,19.81,0,27.37l-15.81,15.81
            l-15.81-15.81C353.93,332.15,353.93,319.9,361.49,312.34z"/>
            <polyline class="st0" points="363.3,310.54 377.31,324.55 391.31,310.54    "/>
            <polyline class="st0" points="358.85,314.98 377.31,333.44 395.76,314.98     "/>
            <polyline class="st0" points="356.41,321.36 377.31,342.25 398.21,321.35     "/>
            <line class="st0" x1="377.31" y1="355.52" x2="377.31" y2="342.41"/>
            <line class="st0" x1="377.31" y1="324.55" x2="377.31" y2="306.35"/>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path class="st0" d="M384.14,321.32L384.14,321.32c-8.73-8.73-8.73-22.89,0-31.63l0,0c7.56-7.56,19.81-7.56,27.37,0l15.81,15.81
              l-15.81,15.81C403.95,328.88,391.7,328.88,384.14,321.32z"/>
              <polyline class="st0" points="382.34,319.51 396.35,305.5 382.34,291.5     "/>
              <polyline class="st0" points="386.79,323.96 405.24,305.5 386.79,287.05    "/>
              <polyline class="st0" points="393.16,326.4 414.05,305.5 393.15,284.6    "/>
              <line class="st0" x1="427.33" y1="305.5" x2="414.21" y2="305.5"/>
              <line class="st0" x1="396.35" y1="305.5" x2="378.16" y2="305.5"/>
            </g>
            <g>
              <path class="st0" d="M370.47,289.69L370.47,289.69c8.73,8.73,8.73,22.89,0,31.63v0c-7.56,7.56-19.81,7.56-27.37,0l-15.81-15.81
                l15.81-15.81C350.66,282.13,362.91,282.13,370.47,289.69z"/>
                <polyline class="st0" points="372.27,291.5 358.26,305.5 372.27,319.51     "/>
                <polyline class="st0" points="367.83,287.05 349.37,305.5 367.83,323.96    "/>
                <polyline class="st0" points="361.46,284.61 340.56,305.5 361.47,326.41    "/>
                <line class="st0" x1="327.29" y1="305.5" x2="340.4" y2="305.5"/>
                <line class="st0" x1="358.26" y1="305.5" x2="376.46" y2="305.5"/>
              </g>
            </g>
            <g>
              <path d="M231.96,314.57h-2.16v-21.24h12.81v1.92h-10.65v7.35h9.9v1.92h-9.9V314.57z"/>
              <path d="M252.72,314.57h-2.16v-21.24h6.24c1.04,0,2,0.1,2.9,0.3c0.89,0.2,1.66,0.53,2.31,0.98c0.65,0.45,1.15,1.04,1.51,1.75
                c0.36,0.72,0.54,1.6,0.54,2.64c0,0.78-0.14,1.49-0.42,2.13c-0.28,0.64-0.66,1.2-1.14,1.67c-0.48,0.47-1.05,0.85-1.71,1.12
                c-0.66,0.28-1.38,0.46-2.16,0.54l6.21,10.11h-2.64l-5.88-9.93h-3.6V314.57z M252.72,302.78h3.75c1.74,0,3.08-0.32,4.02-0.95
                c0.94-0.63,1.41-1.57,1.41-2.83c0-0.7-0.13-1.29-0.39-1.77c-0.26-0.48-0.62-0.87-1.08-1.17c-0.46-0.3-1.02-0.52-1.68-0.66
                c-0.66-0.14-1.39-0.21-2.19-0.21h-3.84V302.78z"/>
              <path d="M274.59,312.65h11.37v1.92h-13.53v-21.24h13.17v1.92h-11.01v7.29h10.29v1.92h-10.29V312.65z"/>
              <path d="M296.25,312.65h11.37v1.92h-13.53v-21.24h13.17v1.92h-11.01v7.29h10.29v1.92h-10.29V312.65z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
              <path d="M456.13,296.75c-0.46-0.64-1.05-1.15-1.77-1.54c-0.72-0.39-1.59-0.58-2.61-0.58c-0.52,0-1.05,0.08-1.59,0.24
                s-1.03,0.41-1.47,0.74c-0.44,0.33-0.79,0.75-1.06,1.24c-0.27,0.5-0.41,1.09-0.41,1.77s0.13,1.24,0.39,1.68
                c0.26,0.44,0.6,0.82,1.03,1.12c0.43,0.31,0.92,0.57,1.47,0.77c0.55,0.2,1.12,0.4,1.72,0.6c0.74,0.24,1.48,0.5,2.23,0.78
                s1.42,0.64,2.02,1.09s1.09,1.02,1.47,1.71c0.38,0.69,0.57,1.57,0.57,2.62c0,1.06-0.2,1.98-0.61,2.75c-0.4,0.77-0.93,1.41-1.58,1.91
                s-1.38,0.87-2.21,1.11c-0.83,0.24-1.67,0.36-2.5,0.36c-0.64,0-1.28-0.07-1.92-0.2c-0.64-0.13-1.25-0.33-1.83-0.58
                s-1.12-0.59-1.62-0.99c-0.5-0.4-0.94-0.86-1.32-1.38l1.86-1.38c0.46,0.76,1.1,1.4,1.93,1.91s1.8,0.76,2.93,0.76
                c0.54,0,1.09-0.08,1.65-0.25s1.07-0.43,1.51-0.78c0.45-0.35,0.82-0.78,1.11-1.29c0.29-0.51,0.44-1.11,0.44-1.79
                c0-0.74-0.15-1.36-0.44-1.85c-0.29-0.49-0.67-0.9-1.16-1.23c-0.48-0.33-1.03-0.6-1.65-0.83c-0.62-0.22-1.27-0.44-1.95-0.66
                c-0.7-0.22-1.39-0.47-2.07-0.75c-0.68-0.28-1.29-0.64-1.83-1.09s-0.97-1-1.3-1.67s-0.5-1.47-0.5-2.43c0-1.02,0.21-1.9,0.62-2.64
                c0.41-0.74,0.95-1.35,1.6-1.83c0.66-0.48,1.39-0.83,2.19-1.05c0.8-0.22,1.59-0.33,2.37-0.33c1.44,0,2.67,0.25,3.69,0.77
                c1.02,0.51,1.79,1.12,2.31,1.81L456.13,296.75z"/>
              <path d="M466.66,293.33h6c1.08,0,2.06,0.12,2.94,0.35c0.88,0.23,1.63,0.58,2.26,1.05s1.12,1.06,1.46,1.77s0.51,1.54,0.51,2.5
                s-0.18,1.8-0.53,2.5c-0.35,0.71-0.84,1.3-1.47,1.77s-1.39,0.83-2.28,1.06c-0.89,0.24-1.88,0.36-2.96,0.36h-3.78v9.87h-2.16V293.33z
                M468.82,302.87h3.66c1.7,0,2.99-0.33,3.87-0.99c0.88-0.66,1.32-1.62,1.32-2.88c0-1.32-0.46-2.28-1.37-2.89s-2.19-0.92-3.83-0.92
                h-3.66V302.87z"/>
              <path d="M490.12,314.57h-2.16v-21.24h2.16V314.57z"/>
              <path d="M501.82,314.57h-2.16v-21.24h6.24c1.04,0,2,0.1,2.89,0.3c0.89,0.2,1.66,0.53,2.31,0.98c0.65,0.45,1.15,1.04,1.51,1.75
                s0.54,1.6,0.54,2.64c0,0.78-0.14,1.49-0.42,2.13c-0.28,0.64-0.66,1.2-1.14,1.67c-0.48,0.47-1.05,0.85-1.71,1.12
                c-0.66,0.28-1.38,0.46-2.16,0.54l6.21,10.11h-2.64l-5.88-9.93h-3.6V314.57z M501.82,302.78h3.75c1.74,0,3.08-0.32,4.02-0.95
                S511,300.26,511,299c0-0.7-0.13-1.29-0.39-1.77c-0.26-0.48-0.62-0.87-1.08-1.17c-0.46-0.3-1.02-0.52-1.68-0.66
                c-0.66-0.14-1.39-0.21-2.19-0.21h-3.84V302.78z"/>
                <path d="M523.69,314.57h-2.16v-21.24h2.16V314.57z"/>
                <path d="M540.04,314.57h-2.16v-19.32h-7.11v-1.92h16.38v1.92h-7.11V314.57z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path d="M290.36,333.98v8.43h-2.56v-8.43h-3v-2.19h8.56v2.19H290.36z"/>
                <path d="M300.21,342.41l-2.31-4.21h-0.87v4.21h-2.5v-10.62h4.05c0.51,0,1.01,0.05,1.49,0.16c0.48,0.11,0.92,0.28,1.3,0.53
                  s0.69,0.58,0.92,0.99c0.23,0.41,0.34,0.92,0.34,1.53c0,0.72-0.19,1.33-0.58,1.82s-0.93,0.84-1.62,1.05l2.77,4.54H300.21z
                  M300.11,335.05c0-0.25-0.05-0.45-0.16-0.61c-0.11-0.15-0.24-0.27-0.41-0.36c-0.17-0.08-0.35-0.14-0.56-0.17s-0.4-0.04-0.6-0.04
                  h-1.37v2.47h1.22c0.21,0,0.43-0.02,0.65-0.05c0.22-0.03,0.42-0.1,0.6-0.19c0.18-0.09,0.33-0.22,0.44-0.39
                  C300.05,335.54,300.11,335.32,300.11,335.05z"/>
                <path d="M311.67,342.41l-0.82-2.08h-4.11l-0.78,2.08h-2.79l4.46-10.62h2.49l4.41,10.62H311.67z M308.82,334.63l-1.35,3.65h2.67
                  L308.82,334.63z"/>
                <path d="M320.22,342.41h-2.56l-4.02-10.62h2.88l2.46,7.53h0.06l2.45-7.53h2.83L320.22,342.41z"/>
                <path d="M325.19,342.41v-10.62h7.14v2.16h-4.67v2.01h4.41v2.06h-4.41v2.2h4.94v2.19H325.19z"/>
                <path d="M334.29,342.41v-10.62h2.58v8.38h4.11v2.24H334.29z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path d="M422.51,342.41l-0.83-2.08h-4.11l-0.78,2.08H414l4.46-10.62h2.49l4.41,10.62H422.51z M419.66,334.63l-1.35,3.65h2.67
                  L419.66,334.63z"/>
                <path d="M433.59,342.43c-0.7,0.17-1.45,0.25-2.27,0.25c-0.85,0-1.63-0.13-2.35-0.4c-0.71-0.27-1.33-0.65-1.84-1.14
                  c-0.51-0.49-0.92-1.08-1.21-1.76c-0.29-0.69-0.44-1.45-0.44-2.29c0-0.85,0.15-1.62,0.44-2.31c0.29-0.69,0.7-1.28,1.22-1.76
                  s1.13-0.86,1.83-1.12c0.7-0.26,1.46-0.39,2.26-0.39c0.84,0,1.62,0.13,2.34,0.38c0.72,0.25,1.3,0.6,1.75,1.03l-1.62,1.84
                  c-0.25-0.29-0.58-0.53-0.99-0.71c-0.41-0.19-0.88-0.28-1.39-0.28c-0.45,0-0.87,0.08-1.25,0.25c-0.38,0.17-0.71,0.4-0.99,0.69
                  c-0.28,0.29-0.5,0.64-0.65,1.05c-0.16,0.41-0.23,0.85-0.23,1.33c0,0.49,0.07,0.94,0.21,1.35c0.14,0.41,0.35,0.76,0.62,1.06
                  c0.28,0.3,0.62,0.53,1.02,0.69c0.4,0.17,0.87,0.25,1.39,0.25c0.3,0,0.58-0.02,0.86-0.07c0.27-0.04,0.52-0.12,0.75-0.22v-1.94h-2.03
                  v-2.07h4.38v5.62C434.89,342.04,434.28,342.26,433.59,342.43z"/>
                  <path d="M437.51,342.41v-10.62h7.14v2.16h-4.67v2.01h4.41v2.06h-4.41v2.2h4.93v2.19H437.51z"/>
                  <path d="M453.36,342.41l-4.28-6.95h-0.04l0.06,6.95h-2.49v-10.62h2.92l4.26,6.93h0.05l-0.06-6.93h2.49v10.62H453.36z"/>
                  <path d="M466.07,342.22c-0.69,0.32-1.49,0.47-2.38,0.47c-0.82,0-1.58-0.13-2.27-0.41c-0.7-0.27-1.3-0.65-1.81-1.15
                    s-0.91-1.09-1.2-1.78c-0.29-0.69-0.43-1.45-0.43-2.28c0-0.85,0.15-1.62,0.44-2.31c0.29-0.69,0.7-1.28,1.22-1.76
                    c0.52-0.49,1.13-0.86,1.83-1.12c0.7-0.26,1.45-0.39,2.26-0.39c0.75,0,1.49,0.13,2.21,0.4c0.73,0.27,1.31,0.65,1.76,1.16l-1.74,1.74
                    c-0.24-0.33-0.56-0.57-0.95-0.73c-0.39-0.16-0.79-0.24-1.2-0.24c-0.45,0-0.86,0.08-1.24,0.25c-0.38,0.16-0.7,0.39-0.97,0.68
                    c-0.27,0.29-0.48,0.63-0.63,1.03c-0.15,0.39-0.22,0.83-0.22,1.3c0,0.48,0.07,0.92,0.22,1.32s0.36,0.74,0.62,1.03
                    c0.27,0.29,0.58,0.51,0.95,0.67c0.37,0.16,0.77,0.24,1.21,0.24c0.51,0,0.96-0.1,1.33-0.3s0.68-0.46,0.92-0.78l1.79,1.68
                    C467.34,341.48,466.76,341.91,466.07,342.22z"/>
                  <path d="M473.88,337.91v4.5h-2.57v-4.5l-3.99-6.12h3.1l2.26,3.93l2.27-3.93h3L473.88,337.91z"/>
            </g>
    </symbol>

  </defs>
</svg>
```

my html:

```
<li class="navigation__logo">
    <svg >
      <use xlink:href="svg/sprite.svg#Layer_1"></use>
    </svg>
</li>
```

Comment: How would you use it as a sprite? In your code you have classes but no `id`s. would you use it as an `<use>`element or as an image? Please edit your question and explain how do you use the sprite.

Comment: @enxaneta I just did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the style from the .svg file (the sprite) and use those roules for the `<use>` element, more or less like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    body{background:black;}
    use{fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:2.0134;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<li class="navigation__logo">
    <svg >
      <use xlink:href="sof.svg#Layer_1"></use>
    </svg>
</li>

</body>
</html>
```

Also you can take a look here: [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/project/editor/8e0a06dfb7f5ac71f79cc5570122698c)

Comment: Now if I make the svg bigger it's visible that it only has a white stroke. If you look at my codepen you'll see that the text has fill but the logo has only stroke. In your codepen, everything has a stroke only.

Comment: In order to fix this you need to add presentational attributes for the text. In my demo I've added `fill="white" stroke="none"` for the text. Please take a look.

Comment: tysm, it worked! what if I want to fill the path with a jpg image? I have used <pattern> to define the image and then reference it inside the svg but again, it works on codepen but not inside a sprite file. The sprite is in the comments of the CSS section here [https://codepen.io/rawan-al-faraj/pen/RvXPzo]